# Rails nested routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-routing

I have Q+A model inside an events model and having issue with understanding how the nested routes work. I'm getting a `No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"event_questions" and` missing required keys: [:event_id]`

My question form sits inside my show.hrml.erb for my event model right now. Some of the relationship stuff is from neo4j gem so it isn't standard but the issue shouldn't be related to that. From what I know, I am posting to /events/events_id/event_questions

events_controller.rb

```
def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @event_question = EventQuestion.new
end
```

event.rb

```
  has_many :out, :event_questions, type: 'questions_of'
```

event_question.rb

```
  has_one :in, :events, origin: :event_questions
```

events/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [:event, @event_question] do |f| %>

#form stuff

<% end %>
```

event_questions_controller.rb

```
def create
    @event_question = EventQuestion.new(event_question_params)
    if @event_question.save
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @event_question.update(admin: current_user.facebook_id)
        @event_question.events << @event
        redirect_to @event
    else
        redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :events do
    resources :event_questions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with

`form_for(@event_question, :url => event_event_questions_path(@event)) do |f|`

I'm not sure how to pass the @event via the other way (in the question), but assuming you can, both methods should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's in your routes. Change it to look like this:

```
resources :events do
  resources :questions, controller: 'event_questions`, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

That'll give you `http://youraddress/event/:event_id/questions` and put it in the expected controller. Make sure it's `event_questions.rb` and not `events_questions.rb`. From terminal, also run `rake routes` and it'll show you the actions, paths, and controllers responsible for them.

Comment: The routes look right to me. it should've been `resources :event_questions` since that's the name of the model. My model is `event_question.rb`

Comment: okay i fixed it by listing it another way. really not sure why this way doesn't work. have another issue.. will post back on the other Q haha..